# Jsoup sends application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of json

Tags: json, jsoup

I am trying to post data as json to an api with Jsoup, but the api gives me an error saying

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

The Jsoup request:

```
Jsoup.connect(apiConfiguration.getHttpBaseAddress()+url)
                .validateTLSCertificates(false)
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .timeout(180000)
                .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                .header("Authorization", apiConfiguration.getLoginString())
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .requestBody(reqBodyStr)//POJO, parsed with Gson --> String
                .execute();
```

It is possible that Jsoup did not changed the content type? I also tried to set the requestBody first, then the content type, but it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is Jsoup, there is a pull request to fix this issue, 
hopefully will be included in the next release (after 1.9.2)

https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/734